Sci-Fi movie where woman flies a ship through a star
My best guess is that this is an 80s or early 90s film. It could be earlier than the 80s, but definitely no later than the early 90s.
All I can recall from the movie was that there was a very intense scene where a woman piloted a single passenger space craft (which I think might have been fairly sleek looking) directly into and through a star. I can't remember the reason for the ship going through the star, but it may have been time travel related. It may not have even been a star, I just seem to recall that she was flying her ship through a bright fire-like atmosphere and she was sweating, but I'm pretty sure she was either flying through the Sun or another star as I always thought that was why that particular scene was so memorable.

I thought it might be Contact, but that's 1997 so doesn't fit the timeframe - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884/

Aye, I should add that it was most likely a B-movie. I think it may have even been a European production that you would generally only be able to catch on channels like HBO and Cinemax. I don't think it was super cheap though, because as far as I remember the special effects were pretty good.

Too recent, but "bright fire-like atmosphere" and "sweating" bring to mind scenes from the third season Battlestar Galatica episode "The Passage", (2006).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passage_(Battlestar_Galactica)

Will, the scene in "The Passage" where Kat is flying through the fire is an almost note for note replication of the scene from the movie I'm thinking of. I really wouldn't be surprised if the writers of BSG had used it for inspiration. I even recall that the reason the woman was flying through the star in the movie was because there was some desparation involved and she was the only hope.

The film is "Solar Crisis." The female pilot of a sleek ship flies into the sun (sweating all the way)  to plant a bomb and set off a solar flare so that it does not hit earth.
I found an Italian dub of the entire film on Youtube, but the last 5 minutes cover exactly what you are describing.
English version of the 5 minute segment referred to:




Looks like the site will not allow links to youtube. Just run a search for it and you will see it.

They do allow links, I just added a video link to the 5min segment you referred to, as an alternative to your link to the entire movie in Italian. Napoleon reedited it so only the shorter video is embedded (and the long one is just a link) rather than both of them.

YES! Thank you Vicpylon! That is indeed the exact movie and scene I was talking about. Excellent work!

@TrishLing Yeah, I wasn't sure if embedding the hole 2 hour movie was the best idea. I don't know if it gives any bandwidth problems (probably not, it's streamed afterall), but I'm not sure it's something to encourage.
